# Use production database as in memory database for integration testing

Tags: c#, asp.net, database, entity-framework

I have 58 tables in my production database, and currently these tables have some initial records. My question: is it possible to somehow copy the production database to an in memory database for testing?

Here is the part where the `DbContext` is set up:

```
var descriptor = services.SingleOrDefault(d => d.ServiceType == typeof(DbContextOptions<AppDbContext>));

if (descriptor != null)
{
    services.Remove(descriptor);
}

services.AddEntityFrameworkInMemoryDatabase();
services.AddDbContext<AppDbContext>(
    options =>
    {
        options.UseInMemoryDatabase("AppInMemoryDb");
    });
```

Comment: Why does it have to be "in memory"? What type of database is it? Is it because you don't want to alter the production database with your tests? This has nothing to do with "in memory". All databases are in memory if you have enough memory to cache the data

Comment: It is a Microsoft SQL Server. I want to run test to check whether the implemented workflow works properly and I need the records from the database. So it doesnt have to be in memory but I cannot modify the production database so, thats why i want to run the tests against a copy database. I thought maybe it is possible to somehow store the database in memory and use it for testing.

Comment: Just backup/restore to a different database. Memory is irrelevant here.

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Okay. Thanks for your help!

Comment: SQL Server has no concept of "in-memory" database. It has a memory cache, but it's totally transparent to clients.